# How to conditionally hide page header in Reporting Services report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Is there any way to conditionally ( based on report parameter for example )
hide/show the page header/footer ?

The PrintOnFirst/PrintOnLastPage obviously work for first page.

I need it to work for the whole report

Like you can hide some column based on a parameter value ..

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot show/hide header and footer based on a report parameter but...

... you can control element visibility, so instead of hiding header/footer hide their items.